# Firestore GET Document Promise does not have a result

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve a document after it is created since Firestore does not return a created document.  I do get the document Reference ID each time, however, when I turn around and use it, the promise is resolved but the retuning object is non-existent it seems.

Here is my code, the part I am struggling with is the section that is nested within the first Add call to Firestore

```
 ideasRef
        .add({
          ideaId: req.body.ideaId,
          title: req.body.title,
          description: req.body.description,
          category: req.body.category,
          competitorHasIt: req.body.competitorHasIt || false,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          createdBy: {
            email: req.body.user.email,
            fullName: `${req.body.user.firstName} ${req.body.user.lastName}`,
            location: req.body.user.location
          },
          deactivated: false
        })
       .then(docRef => {
       console.log(docRef.id)
          ideasRef
            .get(docRef.id)
            .then(idea => {
              console.log("first run")
              console.log(idea.exists())
              console.log(idea.data())
              console.log("do those even run?")
})
```

What is outputted in the console is the docRef.id value and "first run".  What I expected to happen it to see the 3 subsequent console.logs as well that contains information about `idea`

Any advice on what I am overlooking would be greatly appreciated,  my end goal is to get help and realizing why my `idea` object seems to silently cause issues.  I do not see any errors in the terminal.

Comment: So what *does* happen when you run this code? And did you already run it in a debugger, and set some breakpoints for example on those logs?

Comment: I had a co-worker with a fresh set of eyes catch my issue.  I needed .doc(docRef.id).get() and not just .get(docRef.id).  Thank you @FrankvanPuffelen and I will update the code above to be correct.

Comment: Peter3, instead of updating the question with the correct answer, could you post it as an answer in order to provide better visibility to whoever stumbles across a similar issue?

Comment: all set @pessolato

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being the working version.

```
 ideasRef
        .add({
          ideaId: req.body.ideaId,
          title: req.body.title,
          description: req.body.description,
          category: req.body.category,
          competitorHasIt: req.body.competitorHasIt || false,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          createdBy: {
            email: req.body.user.email,
            fullName: `${req.body.user.firstName} ${req.body.user.lastName}`,
            location: req.body.user.location
          },
          deactivated: false
        })
       .then(docRef => {
       console.log(docRef.id)
          ideasRef
            .doc(docRef.id)
            .get()
            .then(idea => {
              console.log("first run")
              console.log(idea.exists())
              console.log(idea.data())
              console.log("do those even run?")
})
```